# selecting a page content in apple script

Tags: applescript

I want to go through a MS Word document page by page and generate images of all pages. I am stuck in the very beginning. Although I can compute total number of pages I cannot get the content of say page 1 into selection object.

I want something like

```
select page 1 of active document
```

or

```
set myRange to create range active document page 1
```

or

```
create range active document start (start of page 1) end (end of page 1)
```

Of course I have the page count and I want to loop on it and generate images page by page but please help me first to get page content into a selection object so that I can proceed.

If anybody has some other idea of accomplishing the job them I am all for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

The steps are.

1. Convert word document to pdf through apple script.
2. Make a work flow in automater to render pdf as images.
3. Call the word flow through shell command from apple script.

I will make a tutorial in few days and post some where.